# Get all items that are past due for all employees - SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

So this is in MS Access - I know, but this is what they have - and the inner query being returned as `i` works if I just set `EMP_FID=3`. As originally written, they just looped through every employee with DAO and passed the value in that place, but because there are now over 1K employees, it takes forever.  I am trying to optimize this and get the desired results in a single query.  I have the following :

```
SELECT e.ID, i.ITM, i.DUE_BY, i.TXT FROM tblEmployees as e, (SELECT tblItems.ITM, tblItems.DUE_BY, tblItems.TXT
FROM tblItems 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITM_FID FROM tblHistory WHERE EMP_FID=e.ID) as h 
ON tblItems.ID = h.ITM_FID 
WHERE h.ITM_FID Is Null  And Int(tblItems.DUE_BY - Now()) <= 0 
ORDER BY tblItems.DUE_BY DESC) as i
```

The query runs, but doesn't return a result when I know it should return a single record.

`tblItems` has a list of things employees need to complete.
`tblHistory` contains the `emp_fid` and the `itm_fid` as well as the date they completed it.
`tblEmployees` has the employees.

As stated earlier, this works:

```
SELECT tblItems.ITM, tblItems.DUE_BY, tblItems.TXT
FROM tblItems 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITM_FID FROM tblHistory WHERE EMP_FID=3) as h 
ON tblItems.ID = h.ITM_FID 
WHERE h.ITM_FID Is Null  And Int(tblItems.DUE_BY - Now()) <= 0 
ORDER BY tblItems.DUE_BY DESC
```

But you don't know which employee it was.  So that is why I am trying to add in the `tblEmployees` to get the `ID` and pass it to the inner query. In order to get all items that are past due for all employees.

If you can just point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I completely over thought this.  I just reworked it to this and it works perfectly:

```
SELECT tblEmployees.ID, tblItems.ITM, tblItems.DUE_BY, tblItems.TXT 
FROM tblEmployees, tblItems 
WHERE 
tblEmployees.ID NOT IN (SELECT EMP_FID FROM tblHistory WHERE ITM_FID=tblItems.ID) 
AND 
 tblItems.ID NOT IN (SELECT ITM_FID FROM tblHistory WHERE EMP_FID=tblEmployees.ID) 
AND 
Int(tblItems.DUE_BY - Now()) <=0 
AND
tblEmployees.ACTV=True
ORDER BY tblItems.DUE_BY DESC
```